# Where do I install my shortcuts to if I want to put them in the Vista/7 "Games" Folder in the start menu?

Tags: installation

As a game developer, I would like for my games to be placed in the proper directory. But I don't know where to install the shortcuts to, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Games folder in Vista isn't a folder containing shortcuts; it's a somewhat strange beast of XML files embedded in your game's EXE and API calls at install time to make the icon and other data (publisher/developer, required and recommended Windows Experience Index scores, etc) appear in the start menu.

The documentation for Games Explorer (the name for the feature) is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd607263(VS.85).aspx); the getting started guide is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb173446(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

A quick search yielded an interesting result:

- [Adding Games to the Vista Game Folder that are not added automatically](http://blog.hexagonstar.com/vistatweak6/)

Comment: So the solution is adding that kind of information to the registry in the install of your software

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 7 I believe it would be C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Games
That's if windows is installed on the C drive.